# Composer fails on update

Tags: symfony, composer-php

I'm trying to update vendors on server, but always process is killed. I think have relationship with memory_limit parameter, but before try on server I made it on my local installation, and didn't happen any error with a low memory_limit param.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don´t `composer update`. You do `composer install`.